# Calculate value of $\pi$ to millionth digit?

Tags: numerical-methods, pi

** I wanted to calculate the value of $\pi$ till millionth digit precision ,but I really cannot think of any proper procedure to calculate it **

Can individual nth digit after decimal be calculated ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula

Comment: I'm asking myself, why you don't like to look in the wikipedia and instead seem to hope, that some people write the same things again here... Wikipedia was made (and is still maintained) exactly to provide encyclopedial facts about items in various fields, such as mathematics and $\pi$ . Hmmm ...